# Which other function could we pick to prove that the union is at the most countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Proposition**:

The union of two sets, both of which is at most countable, is an at most coutable set.

**Proof**:

Without loss of generality, let $A \neq \varnothing, B \neq \varnothing$ be at most countable sets.

That means that there are $f: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\to} A , g: \omega \overset{\text{surjective}}{\to} B$.

We define $h: \omega \times \{0,1 \} \to A \cup B$ as follows:

$$h(\langle n, 0 \rangle)=f(n) \text{ and } h(\langle n, 1 \rangle)=g(n)$$

Since $f,g$ are surjective from the definition of $h$ we have that $h$ is surjective and so $A \cup B$ is at most countable.

Which other function could we pick to prove that $A \cup B$ is at most countable.

In general, how do we choose such functions?

**EDIT**: A set $X$ is at most countable if it is finite or countable. A set $X$ is finite if there is a natural number $n$ such that $X \sim n$, i.e. there is a bijective function from $X$ to $n$. A set $X$ is countable if there is a bijective fuction from $X$ to $\omega$.

Comment: What do you mean by different? Is $h'(2k) = f(k)$ and $h'(2k+1) = g(k)$ different enough, or is it the same as your $h$?

Comment: What does "at most countable" mean? What's less than countable? Also, your statement which "does not lose generality" is not generalizing, so I'm not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: @dtldarek So you take a function from $\omega$ to $A \cup B$ ?

Comment: @GFauxPas A set $X$ is at most countable if it is finite or countable. A set $X$ is finite if there is a natural number $n$ such that $X \sim n$, i.e. there is a bijective function from $X$ to $n$. A set $X$ is countable if there is a bijective fuction from $X$ to $\omega$.

Comment: @evinda In your notation yes, though I would prefer to say $h' : \mathbb{N} \to A \cup B$.

Comment: Ok, in my Set theory course we symbolize it with $\omega$ at which we include the natural number $0$. With $h'$ you don't mean a derivative, just an other function... right? @dtldarek

Comment: @evinda For me $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ as well. About $\omega$, I thought so, also your usage of "countable" is different too; I would use _countably infinite_, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) (and "at most countable" would become just "countable", not "at most countably infinite"). As for $h'$, yep, it's just another name.

Comment: @dtldarek But is it better to take the cartesian product of a finite and an infinite set, since we are talking about at most countable sets?

Comment: @evinda I cannot reply before you answer my first two questions (i.a. if $h'$ is different enough).

Comment: @dtldarek Which question do you mean? If $h'$ is different enough?

Comment: @evinda Yes. Consider $\phi : \mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $\phi(n,b) = 2n+b$, then $h' = h \circ \phi^{-1}$ or $h = h' \circ \phi$.